# Native shell command set to extract node value from XML

Tags: xml, xmllint

I'm trying to extract the value of a node from a pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.me.labs</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-random-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </parent>
    ...
</project>
```

I need to extract the artifactId and version from the XML using a shell command. I have the following requirements/observations:

1. The shell script will be done within a build assembly file we use at work, so the smaller the script the better.
2. Since it'll be used on multiple systems (usually RHEL5), I'm looking for something that can run natively on default images.
3. Tags like  can occur elsewhere in the pom, so I can't simply awk for those tags.

I have tried the following:

1. **`xpath`** works on my Mac, but isn't available by default on RHEL machines. Similarly for `xmllint --xpath`, which I guess is only available on later versions of `xmllint`, which I don't have and can't enforce.
2. **`xmllint --pattern`** seemed promising, but I can't seem to get an output out of `xmllint --pattern '//project/parent/version' pom.xml` (prints entire XML) or `xmllint --stream --pattern '//project/parent/version' pom.xml` (no output).

I realize this is a common question here on SO, but the points above are why I can't use those answers. TIA for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've managed to solve it for the time being with this rather unwiedly script using `xmllint --shell`.

```sh
echo "cat //project/parent/version" | xmllint --shell pom.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
```

If the XML nodes have namespace attributes like my pom.xml had, things get heavier, basically extracting the node by name:

```sh
echo "cat //*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='parent']/*[local-name()='version']" | xmllint --shell pom.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
```

Hope it helps. If anyone can simply these expressions, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use this: `echo "cat //*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='parent']/*[local-name()='version']/text()" | xmllint --shell pom.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d'`, so you only need to `sed`-remove the xmllint shell stuff

Comment: If you have a recent enough `xmllint`, then you don't need the `--shell` stuff: `xmllint --xpath /*[local-name()=="project"]/...' pom.xml`. The `local-name()` part was what I was missing for my script.

Comment: Thank you for you answer 
`echo "cat //*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='parent']/*[local-name()='version']" | xmllint --shell pom.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
`

Answer (score 29):

`--format` is used only to format (indent, etc) the document. You can do that using `--xpath` (tested in Ubuntu, libxml v20900):

```
$ xmllint --xpath "//project/parent/version/text()" pom.xml
1.5.0
```

Comment: Like I said, my version of `xmllint` doesn't seem to support the `--xpath` option. And I don't want to chance that it'll be available on my build systems.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't noticed. python/libxml2 is an option?

Comment: Also: `xpath  -q -e "//project/parent/version/text()" pom.xml`

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from third party libraries (`libxml2`) or any tools (`xpath`) I can't guarantee will be available on a Linux machine.I guess if no combination of the native tools can be used, I'll have to hack it somehow.

Comment: With regard to your answer, I meant `xmllint --pattern`. I've made the change in the post.

Answer (score 6):

I came here looking for a nice way to scrape a value from a website. The following example may be useful to those (unlike the poster) who have a version of xmllint which supports --xpath.

I needed to pull the most recent stable version of the elasticsearch .debfile and install it. The maintainers have helpfully put the version number in a span with the class "version".

```
version=`curl -s http://www.elasticsearch.org/download/ |\
 xmllint --html --xpath '//span[@class="version"]/text()'\
 2>/dev/null - `;
```

What goes on:

We use the curl -s (silent) option.

```
curl -s http://www.elasticsearch.org/download/
```

We use the xmllint --html and --xpath switches. The xpath arguments (in single quotes)

```
'//span[@class="version"]/text()'
```

... looks for a <span> node with the class attribute (@class) "version", and extracts the text value (/text()).

Since xmllint is (surprise!) a linter, it will squawk about the inevitable garbage in your html stream. We direct the stderr to /dev/null in the usual way:

```
 2>/dev/null
```

Finally, note the " - " at the end of the xmllint command, which tells xmllint the stream is coming from stdin.

Comment: Karthik. V, this is not a good answer for you, but your question is well-named, so it's pretty high up in a google search. I thought I'd add this for people like me who are looking for a quick answer and have different tools.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `text()` XPath function gives you the element value, rather than having to remove the XML tags:

```
echo "cat //project/parent/version/text()" | xmllint --shell pom.xml
```

Comment: Sorry text() doesn't work nor does `/value/text()` What version of libxml2 are you using? I have 2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

You can try

`xmllint --xpath "/*[name()='project']/*[name()='groupId']/text()" pom.xml`

Comment: It worked fine. I tried earlier -xpath is unknow. I just copied your answer and mondified as per my requirement and It working....!!!

Answer (score 0):

With POMs you may issue problems with namespaces which prevent *xmllint* to work as expected. [This articles](http://blog.powered-up-games.com/wordpress/archives/70) points you to an alternative and very good solution (look at **sed** paragraph).