# Get Node value from a XML using xmllint

Tags: unix, xmllint

I have a xml called Det.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
            <ns4:grtHgetRed xmlns:ns2="http://object" xmlns:ns3="http://object" xmlns:ns4="http://object">
                <RequestId>lol</RequestId>
                <MessageDateTime>54.009</MessageDateTime>
                <SenderId>UH</SenderId>
                <ReceiverId>GER</ReceiverId>
                <TrackingNumber>45</TrackingNumber>
                <ServerName>trewds</ServerName>
                <ResponseType>success</ResponseType>
                <StatusInfo>
                <Status>success</Status>
                <SystemMessage>Hagert</SystemMessage>
                <UserMessage>Hgert</UserMessage>
                <Origination>htref</Origination>
                </StatusInfo>
            </ns4:grtHgetRed>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

I am trying to get the `ResponseType` node value `success` from it using `xmllint` in Unix shell script and so i tried the following :

```
echo "cat //*[local-name()='S:Envelope'/*[local-name()='S:Body']/*[local-name()='ns4:grtHgetRed']/*[local-name()='ResponseType']" | xmllint --shell Det
.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
```

But it's not working . Also i don't  have `xpath` in my unix environment . Can any one tell me what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Native shell command set to extract node value from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959908/native-shell-command-set-to-extract-node-value-from-xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `local-name()` is just the bit after the colon, so instead of e.g. `local-name()='S:Envelope'` try just `local-name()='Envelope'`.

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='grtHgetRed']/*[local-name()='ResponseType']
```

Or you may want to consider an alternative tool such as [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) which has better support for this kind of thing.

Comment: I tried this one `statusMSG=="$(echo "cat /Envelope/Body/grtHgetRed/ResponseType/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell response.xml | sed '1d;$d')"` Then when i do `echo "$statusMSG"`, i find the echo to be empty .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight `/Envelope/...` definitely won't work because that would be looking for an element with no namespace, and your XML has it in the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only ever a single ResponseType element in the XML, use the following to simplify things:

```
echo 'cat //ResponseType/text()' | xmllint --shell det.xml
```

The `//` is XPath syntax for "find this element anywhere in the document".

The `text()` function returns the contents of the element, meaning you do not need the further massage the result with `sed` et. al.

This worked for me on both a Solaris and Linux box for which `xmllint` does not have the `--xpath` option available.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing wrong... If using XMLlint is not mandatory, you can use JDom, works like a charm for requirements like yours... Just a suggestion...