# How to extract values from an xml file using shell script?

Tags: xml, shell, awk, grep, xmllint

I have this xml file.

```
<body>
<part1>
   <para1>abc</para1>
   <para2>def</para2>
   <ver>1234</ver>
</part1>    
</body>
```

I need to store the value given by *`ver`* i.e. `1234` in a variable.

Comment: That question isn't *quite* a duplicate... It's about extracting an attribute value, not the body of a tag. The answer is going to be very similar, though - just a bit different XPath expression.

Comment: Yes @Shawn, I went through a lot of questions in which the value was present in the tag itself. I tried modifying those answers but couldn't reach a solution. Thanks for reopening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different options:

1. using `xmlstarlet`:

```sh
ver=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m //ver -v . test.xml)
```

2. using `xmllint` (see also [Native shell command set to extract node value from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959908/native-shell-command-set-to-extract-node-value-from-xml):

```sh
ver=$(xmllint --xpath "//ver/text()" test.xml)
```

3. Using `gawk`:

```sh
ver=$(gawk -F "[><]" '/<ver>/{ print $3 }' test.xml)
```

Comment: The awk one (and it's common to all awks, not gawk-specific) would be more robust as `awk -F'[<>]' '$2=="ver"{ print $3 }'`. That would not fail if `<ver>` just happened to exist in some other string in the input.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I will always leave some improvement for you 

Comment: Using [tag:xidel]: `ver=$(xidel -s test.xml -e '//ver')` or `eval "$(xidel -s test.xml -e 'ver:=//ver' --output-format=bash)"`